# Calling C++ function from Excel and VBA using DLL created in C++

Tags: c++, vba, excel, dll

I created a DLL containing a function named "koduj". Calling this function by using it inside an Excel worksheet cell returns the desired result. Calling "koduj" from VBA returns wrong answer.

koduj needs two arguments: `string nr_id` and `integer x1`. It calculates sum of `nr_id`'s letters in ASCII representation and adds `x1`. Calculated sum is than returned.

I was following instructions found [here](https://sites.google.com/site/jrlhost/links/excelcdll).

Here's my .cpp sourcefile:

```cpp
#include<Windows.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;


//Convert BSTR to wstring for convenience
wstring BSTR_to_wstring (BSTR text){
    return wstring(text, SysStringLen(text));
}

//Calculate sum of letters in ASCII representation
int ASCII_sum (wstring ws){
    int sum = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ws.length(); i++)
        sum += ws[i];
    return sum;
}

//"koduj" function
int _stdcall koduj (BSTR nr_id, int & x1){
    wstring ws_nr_id = BSTR_to_wstring(nr_id);
    return ASCII_sum(ws_nr_id) + x1;
}
```

Here's my VBA function declaration:

```vb
Declare Function koduj _
Lib "<dll_directory_and_full_name>" (ByVal x As String, ByRef y As Integer) As Integer
```

By writing:

```
=koduj("aaa";1)
```

Inside a worksheet cell I get desired result (292)

Debugging this VBA code:

```vb
Sub test()

Dim a As Integer
a = koduj("aaa", 1)

End Sub
```

reveals wrong result (a = 24930)

I believe my C++ code is fine, as it works properly when called from Excel's worksheet.

Comment: Try dimensioning `a` as Variant - do you get the same result?

Comment: @enderland that's right, the same (wrong) value.

Comment: This is interesting to me. I've replicated the same issue on my machine, also note that koduj("***") of any three lowercase characters returns the same value. Also note that if you do `Debug.Print koduj("Ab", 1) - koduj("Aa", 1)` you get 256, which strikes me as quite odd.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that even though VBA strings are internally UTF-16, VB always converts them to ASCII before talking to the outside world (`Declare`d functions, file input/output). So when you `Declare` a parameter `As String`, VBA [automatically converts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23980044/11683) the string and passes it out as ASCII. The matching parameter type on the C++ side should be `LPSTR` or `LPCSTR`.

If you want to use `BSTR` on the C++ side, you need to also create an IDL file for that function, compile it into a TLB and reference the TLB from VBA, only then VBA will respect and use `BSTR`.

Another problem is that C++'s `int` translates to VBA's `Long`.

The reason why it works when called from Excel sheet is that apparently Excel [ignores the VBA rules for string conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22298240/11683). I believe this to be a bug.

Answer (score -1):

Try declare a as long:
Dim a As Long

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing from the magnitude of the error that it's the numeric parameter that's going wrong - I would try more explicitly declaring the parameter type in your test VBA routine (probably Integer) and accepting it as that specific type on the C++ side (signed short, in that case).

There's a great Microsoft article about all this at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687915(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687915%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

Not intended to be a complete answer, but your second parameter's type looks wrong.

Your DLL function:
`int _stdcall koduj (BSTR nr_id, int & x1)`
declares `x1` as a *reference* to a (presumably) 32-bit integer.

Your VBA declaration:
`Declare Function koduj Lib "<dll_directory_and_full_name>" (ByVal x As String, ByRef y As Integer) As Integer`
declares y as a *pointer* to a *16-bit* integer.

I'd suggest try changing VBA declaration as follows:

`Declare Function koduj _
Lib "<dll_directory_and_full_name>" (ByVal x As String, ByVal y As Long) As Long`

And, switching your DLL function signature to pass x1 by value:

`int _stdcall koduj (BSTR nr_id, int x1)`

Comment: Yes, the Integer/Long situation is as you describe and should be fixed. However it has nothing to do with the string not arriving as bstr.