# Using DLL in ExcelVBA made from C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, excel, dll, vba

I am importing a function into Excel VBA from a DLL.  The DLL was created in Microsoft Visual C++ (with a mostly unmodified version of the default example).  The return value of the function call in VB is not correct, but I do not know the reason why.

The value I see is 0, but I expect to get a value of 42.

I found an almost identical question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19214209/2487785).  I tried their experiment, where I called the function from the spreadsheet.  I saw the same behavior, the spreadsheet return was correct and the return in vba code was not.

The C++ code looks like this:

**addnum.h**

```
#ifdef ADDNUM_EXPORTS
#define ADDNUM_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define ADDNUM_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" {
ADDNUM_API int  fnaddnum(void);
}
```

**addnum.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "addnum.h
ADDNUM_API int fnaddnum(void)
{
    return 42;
}
```

The VB code looks like this:

```
Declare Function fnaddnum _
   Lib " ... path to dll ... " _
   () As Integer


Sub use_dll()
   Dim return_val As Integer
   return_val = fnaddnum()
   MsgBox ("Value is" & Str(return_var))
End Sub
```

Comment: You have a calling convention mismatch. The VBA is stdcall, the C++ code is cdecl.

Comment: @david heffeman Yes, that is the fundamental issue.  Since, I must use stdcall, I can't use __declspec(dllimport).  Since I'm not using __declspec(dllimport), I need a def file.

Comment: You can use dllexport with stdcall

Comment: Sorry to speak untruths.  What I meant was that I have not gotten VBA to accept dll's with dllexport and stdcall together since I've been working on it.  Because it could be my error, I can't rightly conclude that they *can't* be used together in this context.  I'm just happy I can get something to work now.  Thanks.

Comment: You just need to use the decorated name. Or a def file, but you knew that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I had a typo.  I was referencing 'return_var' instead of 'return_val'.  Indeed, the dll function reference was returning the value correctly.