# VBA call same C++ dll return different results

Tags: c++, vba, excel, dll

I have a test dll function that reads a string and display it:

```
int _stdcall test(LPSTR myString) {
MessageBoxA(NULL, (LPCSTR)myString, "test", MB_OK);
return 0;}
```

The excel VBA declaration is

```
Declare Function test Lib "test.dll" (ByVal text As String) As Long
```

There is a sub that calls the function. It reads an excel cell with value as "abcde" and is able to display a correct result. The sub code is:

```
sub testCode()
    test (cells(1,1).value)
end sub
```

However when call the dll function using excel formula `=test(A1)`, the message box only display the first char "a" of the string.

I had spent entire weekend reading BSTR, etc, still not be able to solve this. What is going on here?

Answer (score 2):

Excel pass a `BSTR` to your C++ code. Each character is coded with 2 bytes, the second one being 0 for common characters. That explains why you see only the first one, as `MessageBoxA` expects char* null terminated strings. Use

> MessageBox**W**

Try with that code

```
int _stdcall test( const wchar_t * pString ) {
   MessageBoxW( NULL, pString, L"test", MB_OK ); // note the L prefix for literral
   return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you could translate the BSTR pointer to a char* one, using some ATL macros, or raw Win32 APIs as [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130.aspx) (more tricky, mush simpler to use ATL)

Comment: This is wrong. VB(A) converts strings to ASCII according to the current system code page when calling to `Declare`d APIs. The only case when it is not true is when the APIs come from a type library. However, Excel might pass something else, but exposing `Declare`d functions directly to Excel sheet engine is something I'd never even think about.

Comment: @GSerg You may be right, I am a C++ guy, not a VBA one. But when a xxxA function displays only the first character, it's because the passed pointer is a wchar_t* one, not a char*.

Comment: The only thing that is *wrong* with your answer is `VB pass`. Replacing it with `Excel pass` makes the answer (likely) correct.

Comment: <br/> Here is another wield things: now the function call can display the word in the right way. However the sub now displays grabled characteristics <br/> I want to make it my weekend homework - btw is there any good reference book re excel VBA and dll?

Comment: @AllanD I may help again, but I don't understand your new problem. Update your question with the code you use now, and explain more clearly what doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Declare your imported function as private:

```vb
Private Declare Function test_internal Lib "test.dll" Alias "test" (ByVal text As String) As Long
```

and create a wrapper function for Excel to use:

```vb
Public Function Test (ByVal text As String) As Long
  Test = test_internal(text)
End Functin
```

Because apparently, while VB(A) converts string arguments to ASCII using the current system codepage when calling to `Declare`d APIs, the Excel engine does not.

On a side note, you also might want to [remove parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8070104/11683).