# XML file with accented chars (e.g. FRONTIÈRES) that don't write to MS Access table correctly (e.g. FRONTIÃˆRES)

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access-2016, diacritics

I have a large XML file that I open.  I use VBA to loop through each line and do some boring editing and then write to a table.  The French characters get messed up.  Another example:

SCT DIVERSITÉ becomes SCT DIVERSITÃ‰

Open "BIGLIST.XML" For Input As #1

```
Do Until EOF(1)
   Line Input #1, ReadData 
   XMLLine = Replace(LTrim(RTrim(ReadData)), "'", "''") ' Using Replace to deal with single quotes
```

' A whole bunch of data transformation takes place

```
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO [TableName] (Field Names) VALUES (All the boring variables I make)"
Loop
Close #1
```

Comment: Unless your computer's codepage for non-Unicode programs matches the encoding of that XML file, you [cannot use `Line Input`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23980044/11683) on it. Why don't you properly load it with MSXML? On a side note, judging by the `Replace`, you need to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/11683 too.

Comment: The Access import of this particularly horrible XML file chopped it into disconnected tables with no way to connect them with certainty. (i.e. no PKs or FKs).  Therefore I was doing it a more difficult way that allowed me to import just the pieces I need.

Comment: Do not use the Access import. Use the MSXML directly.

Comment: Don't read XML as if it were plain text. Always use a real XML parser, which knows how to recognise the encoding of the file.

Comment: "Therefore I was doing it a more difficult way that allowed me to import just the pieces I need." - An optimisation that does things wrong is not an optimisation, it's a bug.

Comment: I have never used the MSXML parser and with search I can't even figure out how to load it.  Suggestions on XML parsers that might be at my low intellectual level?