# What do the different modes in particular "random" in the Open statement do? (VBA)

Tags: vba, file

In VBA, what do the different modes in the [Open statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/open-statement) do and how do I use them?

As far as I understand:

- Output: Write to file, overwrite any existing file
- Append: Appends to an existing file
- Input: Read from file (needs to read a file sequentially)
- Random: Read/Write to/from a file (non-sequential, needs fixed data length)
- Binary: For binary files

Two questions here:

- Does it mean all except "Binary" relate only to Unicode files?
- What would be a simple example for "Random" usage including the reading/writing part (trying to get a grasp for the last hour or so)

Comment: 1) No, VBA [does not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23980044/11683) natively work with Unicode files in principle, and 2) This is for when you have a database in a text file, with each record having the same length, people have really stopped doing that in the last couple of decades.