# Random characters from casting Arduino string to Excel BSTR through c++ DLL

Tags: c++, excel, vba, memory, bstr

So in some Arduino code I am `Serial.print` a few numbers like this (`var1=##,var2=##,var3=##`). I have a C++ DLL that I am making to get this information and Parse it into a variant array like this (`"var1=",##.##,"var2=",##.##,"var3=",##.##`) storing the string portions as variant BSTRs and the `#`s as Variant doubles. This variant array comes from Excel and the purpose of my C++ DLL is to allow serial communications to and from Excel and an Arduino board.

My problem is that instead of getting the information back like I would like, I am instead getting a lot of extra gibberish at the end and cant figure out where it is coming from. I am including my related code before, leaving out the serial communications because I know that that part works for sure. For now, the Arduino Code is just sending (`##,##,##`) then `Serial.println();` to make things simpler as there are no strings, just numbers.

The VBA Code:

```vb
'collects all rows available currently up to 1000(global numRows) lines each time, stores result in dataArray
Public Function getAllData()
    Dim stringArray() As Variant
    Dim variantArray() As Variant

    ReDim stringArray(0 To 3000) As Variant
    ReDim variantArray(0 To 3000) As Variant


    If Main.dataCollectionActive Then
        Dim staringDataRow As Integer
        staringDataRow = currentDataRow

        Dim returnValue As Long

        returnValue = GetAllDataTypes(stringArray(), variantArray(), currentDataRow)
        If Not (returnValue = 0) Then
            If Not (returnValue = -1) Then
                If printWhileCollectingData = True Then
                    ' Call printVariantData
                    Dim row As Integer
                    Dim col As Integer
                    For row = startingDataRow To (currentDataRow - 1)
                        Main.dataBox.Text = Main.dataBox.Text & stringArray(row)
                        For col = 0 To (getNumColumns() - 1)
                             Main.Cells(row + startingRow, col + startingCol).Value = variantArray(col + (row * getNumColumns()))
                        Next col
                    Next row
                End If
            End If
        End If

        'only stoped in Main sheets code for stopDataButton or if the array has reached its limit
        If Not ((currentDataRow * getNumColumns) = UBound(variantArray())) Then
            Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "getAllData"
        End If
        Main.Range("$L$4").Value = currentDataRow
    End If
End Function
```

The C++ DLL code:

```cpp
//end1 comes before end2, so end1 = i-1 and end2 = i characters
DLL_EXPORT bool WINAPI isEndLine(char end1, char end2){
    //check for CRLF
    if (end1 == '\r') {
        if (end2 == '\n') {
            return true;
        }
    }

    //check for normal endLine \0
    else if ((end1 == '\0')) {
        return true;
    }

    //check for users own endLine character
    else{
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_ENDLINE_LENGTH; i++){
            if (end1 == endLine[i]){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

//reads a single character from buffer, if there is nothing returned then the global, bufferAvailable is set to false, so that no more characters are asked for, for now
DLL_EXPORT char WINAPI readCharFromSerial() {
    char dataChar[1];
    DWORD dwBytesRead = 0; //number of data bytes read in
    if(!ReadFile(hSerial, dataChar, 1, &dwBytesRead, NULL)) { //gets data if successful, if not then notifies user
        ErrorExit("ReadFile, reading a character");
    }
    if (dwBytesRead == 0) {
        bufferAvailable = false;
    }
    return dataChar[0]; //returns read in data
}

//reads a single line by pulling one character at a time until it finds the end of line character, if the buffer has characters in it
DLL_EXPORT void WINAPI readLineFromSerialPort(char* line, int length) {
    bufferAvailable = true;
    int i = 0;
    line[i] = readCharFromSerial();
    i++;
    if (bufferAvailable){
        do{
            line[i] = readCharFromSerial();
            i++;
        }while((!isEndLine(line[i-2], line[i-1])) && (i < length));

        if(line[i-2] == '\r') {
            line[i-2] = '\n';
            line[i-1] = '\0';
        }

        if(!(i<length)){
            MessageBoxA(NULL, (LPCSTR)("string length not long enough"), TEXT("readLineFromSerialPort"), MB_OK);
        }
    }
}


DLL_EXPORT void WINAPI PlaceDblInVarDbl(varArr* VD, double data) {
    (VD->ptr[VD->index]).vt = VT_R8; //FIXME add function to do this
    (VD->ptr[VD->index]).dblVal = data;
    VD->index++;
}

DLL_EXPORT void WINAPI PlaceCharPtrInVarBstr(varArr* VD, char* cString) {
    BSTR bstr = new OLECHAR[MAX_DATA_LENGTH];
    const char* Cstring = (const char*)cString;
    mbstowcs(bstr, Cstring, MAX_DATA_LENGTH);
    VD->ptr[VD->index].vt = VT_BSTR;
    SysReAllocString(&((VD->ptr[VD->index]).bstrVal), bstr);
    VD->index++;
}

DLL_EXPORT int  WINAPI ParseCharPtrToVarBstrAndVarDbl(varArr* VD, char* dataString) {
    //FIXME perhaps make an array of chars for strings that are allowed without being coppied, this would be added to the if begging with !isdigit (like the '.')
    bool hasLetters = false;
    int endIndex = 0;
    int startIndex = 0;
    //    MessageBoxA(NULL, (LPCSTR)("entered"), TEXT("ParseCharPtrToVarBstrAndVarDbl"), MB_OK);
    while (!(isEndLine(dataString[endIndex], dataString[endIndex+1]))) {
        hasLetters = false;
        startIndex = endIndex;
        while (!isDelim(dataString[endIndex]) && (!(isEndLine(dataString[endIndex-1], dataString[endIndex])))) {
            if (!(isdigit(dataString[endIndex])) && !(dataString[endIndex] == ' ') && !(dataString[endIndex] == '.')) {
                hasLetters = true;
            }
            endIndex++;
        }
       // MessageBoxA(NULL, (LPCSTR)("delimeter found"), TEXT("ParseCharPtrToVarBstrAndVarDbl"), MB_OK);
        if((startIndex + 1 == endIndex) || (startIndex == endIndex)/* && !(isEndLine(dataString[endIndex-1], dataString[endIndex]))*/) {
            //FIXME odd way to fix CRLF problem
           // MessageBoxA(NULL, (LPCSTR)("triggered if"), TEXT("ParseCharPtrToVarBstrAndVarDbl"), MB_OK);
        }
        else if (hasLetters) { //string
            char smallerString[MAX_DATA_LENGTH];
            const char* DStr = (const char*)(&(dataString[startIndex]));
            strncpy(smallerString, DStr, endIndex-startIndex+1);
            smallerString[endIndex-startIndex+1] = '\0';
            PlaceCharPtrInVarBstr(VD, smallerString);
           // MessageBoxA(NULL, (LPCSTR)("triggered hasLetters"), TEXT("ParseCharPtrToVarBstrAndVarDbl"), MB_OK);
        }
        else { //double
            //FIXME remove whitespace
            char* start = &dataString[startIndex];
            char* eOS = &(dataString[endIndex]);
            char** endOfString = &eOS;

            double data = strtod(start, endOfString);
            //FIXME do some error checking
            PlaceDblInVarDbl(VD, data);
           // MessageBoxA(NULL, (LPCSTR)("triggered does not hasLetters"), TEXT("ParseCharPtrToVarBstrAndVarDbl"), MB_OK);
        }
        endIndex++;
    }
   //, MessageBoxA(NULL, (LPCSTR)("exited"), TEXT("ParseCharPtrToVarBstrAndVarDbl"), MB_OK);
    return VD->startingIndex - VD->index;
}

//first read a lines from the serial port and then parse it into dataArray, does this until there is no data in buffer or array is full
//returns how many rows that it read
DLL_EXPORT int WINAPI GetAllDataTypes(LPSAFEARRAY* unparsedData, LPSAFEARRAY* parsedData, int* currentDataRow) {
    bufferAvailable = true;
    varArr UPD;
    OpenVariantSafeArray(&UPD, unparsedData, *currentDataRow); if (UPD.failed) { return -1; }
    varArr PD;
    OpenVariantSafeArray(&PD, parsedData, *currentDataRow);    if (PD.failed)  { return -1; }

    while (bufferAvailable && ((PD.index + 10) < PD.uBound)) {
        char dataString[MAX_DATA_LENGTH];
        readLineFromSerialPort(dataString, MAX_DATA_LENGTH);
        if (bufferAvailable) {
            PlaceCharPtrInVarBstr(&UPD, dataString);
            ParseCharPtrToVarBstrAndVarDbl(&PD, dataString);
        }
    }

    CloseVariantSafeArray(&UPD, unparsedData); if (UPD.failed) { return -1; }
    CloseVariantSafeArray(&PD, parsedData);    if (PD.failed)  { return -1; }
    *currentDataRow +=  UPD.index - UPD.startingIndex;
    bufferAvailable = true;
    return UPD.index - UPD.startingIndex;
}
```

The Resulting Error:

This is the unparsed String that is returned as it is printed in a textbox in Excel.

```
0.00,0.01,0.00
0.10,0.02,0.01
0.20,0.03,0.02
0.30,0.04,0.03
0.40,0.05,0.04
0.50,0.06,0.05
0.60,0.07,0.06
0.70,0.08,0.07
0.80,0.09,0.08
0.90,0.10,0.09
1.00,0.10,0.10
```

However the parsed string that is printed in cells by VBA for loops. Still has random characters. It appears that there is something wrong with my parsing in DLL as the last double always ends up being a string, and then it always has random strings afterward.

```
0.000   0.010   "0.00
"
-   0.100   0.020
"0.01
"   -   0.200
0.030   "0.02
"   -
0.300   0.040   "0.03
"
-   0.400   0.050
0.900   0.100   "0.09
"
-   0.000   0.100
"0.10
"   -   0.100
0.110   "0.11
"   -
0.200   0.120   "0.12
"
-   0.300   0.130
"0.13
"   -   0.400
0.140   "0.14
"   -
0.500   0.150   "0.15
"
-   0.600   0.160
"0.16
"   -   
"0.25
"   -   0.600
0.240   "0.26
"   -
0.700   0.250   "0.27
"
-
```

Comment: `'/r'` and `'/0'` aren't the same as `'\0'` and `'\r'`. Turn the warnings up in your compiler.

Comment: No way to mark it as answered without an actual answer. Probably best to just delete the question and post a new one later if needed.

Comment: I have updated the question. I have narrowed it down now to being a problem with the parsing in the DLL

Comment: The particular example I took from excel had a visible '-' character but it still does random stuff not just "-".

Comment: I believe the problem is in ParseCharPtrToVarBstrAndVarDbl() and its while loop and if statement conditions, but I cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: @jsotola im afraid that it is not real data.

Comment: can you modify your arduino code to send known data?

Comment: Yes it currently is. it sends 0.00, 0.01, 0.00 then it increments like so +=0.1, +=0.01, +=0.01. The second occasionally does not increment for an iteration or two and once it reaches 1.00 it stays there. And once the third reaches 1.00 it resets. Pretty much every number should be incremental.

Comment: it works now thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final endIndex++ in ParseCharPtrToVarBstrAndVarDbl() in DLL code to skip the delimiter skipped over the null terminator in the strings. The fix is to add a final if statement for the end of string and if it is then return.